# Keycloak Missing parameters: client_id

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I'm trying to hit keycloak installed in docker container behind an nginx server. That's passing it with proxy_pass.

The query is `http://example.compute.amazonaws.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-<ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=a4b04d6b-b490-41ef-8974-f99cf210129d&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=9f67c39b-2312-48cd-980f-ca08f265504d`

However when I want to go through to the admin console I get a screen with "Missing parameters: client_id".

Anyone have any ideas? Logging locations etc, any assistance would be incredible.

Update:

What is logged on that request is only:

`10:57:26,916 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=<anotherip>, error=invalid_request`

Comment: Did you see `server.log`?

Answer (score 1):

The fault was with the NGINX config that was stripping the URL params off.

Solution was to add `$is_args$args` to the proxy_pass url.